# Should I use Nullables or a unique value for structs?

Tags: c#, struct, null, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I'm refactoring my program, switching from classes to structs in order to squeeze more performance out of it. I need a value or method to replace 'null' in my code. C# provides the `Nullable` type (i.e. `StructName?`), but it looks like it's more of a special class for wrapping other types rather
than some sort of special null value I can trust to retain performance.

```cs
Node? temp = _closedList[_closedList.IndexOf(current)];
if (temp == null as Node) return null;
do {
    _path.Push(temp.Value);
    RecordState();
    temp = getNode(temp.Value.ParentPosition);
} while (temp.HasValue && temp.Value.Position != startNode.Position);
```

My other and possibly better idea is to create a special value that represents 'null', using something like `Int32.MaxValue` for all the relevant fields, and then a getter that checks for these special values. This sounds like it'll retain performance as far as I know, but it won't look super nice.

```cs
Node temp = _closedList[_closedList.IndexOf(current)];
if (temp.IsNull) return null;
do {
    _path.Push(temp);
    RecordState();
    temp = getNode(temp.ParentPosition);
} while (!temp.IsNull && temp.Position != startNode.Position);
```

I've looked at a lot of different sources around this, one said that Nullables are terrible, another said they're fine, and someone suggested unique values as a replacement. What should I do?

Note: Above code wasn't tested, I just edited to what I think a Nullable/Null Value implementation might look like.

Comment: So you have a performance problem with nullable types?

Comment: The thing is here, nullable is already a struct, not a class, its already baked into the compiler and specification with all sorts of lifting and magic, and it is already optimised. I fear anything you do otherwise will not achieve what you want... Though truthfully(and likely) i might not be fully understanding what you want to achieve

Comment: No, I haven't tested this because I don't want to spend 1-2 hours fixing my code and am curious if someone could just tell me the ideal solution. A little selfish, but I hope you understand what I mean. I currently do not have any benchmarking setup, so I wouldn't know the most performant solution, either.

Comment: First step, download BenchmarkDotNet, get to know it like your shoes, best thing you will ever do

Comment: Technically my project is based in Unity, so I worry about compatibility. Hmm.

Comment: Yeah unity has its own set of profilers i believe. BenchmarkDotNet is not really going to help (more than just trivially) when compiling to different platforms (the way it does)